# MS-Access Form for multiple queries

Tags: ms-access

Ok here is my dilemma and I am sure more experienced Access users have an easy solution. I have been manually running a set of queries to pull data for business users, that I want to create a form for so they can just run it themselves. This would be easy if it was one query, but the way I have to pull the correct data is first have to run one query that creates a table. I then use that 'new' table in a secondary query to get the data I need.

That first make table query needs to take inputs like supplier number and date range. I then use that output table in another query that sums up total dollar value of purchase orders. I can not include these two steps in one query as it creates an ambiguous outer join.

Any ideas on how I would go about creating a form for something like this?

Comment: If the first Make-Table query drops and creates the same query, ie named the same, you can create your second query binding those fields to whatever instance of that make table is there, assuming same name

Comment: Yep I am an idiot. Your suggestion would work, but I actually came up with even easier way, NOT make a table, just save the first query and bring that over to the second query and make a form off the two joined queries.

Answer (score 1):

Well after re-thinking this I think I was OVER thinking it. Instead of creating a table in the first step, I can just save it as a query and join that query to the second query. Then make a form off the two queries.